# Accessing publish properties in the ready : function

Tags: polymer

How can I access the published properties in the ready : function of my custom element. I can get it if someone passes it in, but I want to check agains the default value. I.e.:

```
Polymer('post-card', {
    publish: {
        inline : false
    },
    ready:function(){
              // returns what's passed in
          var passedIn = this.getAttribute('inline'), 

              // returns null when inline is not present on the element
              default = this.getAttribute('inline') ;
    }
});
```

I know the default variable is looking for the attribute "inline" on the elemnt. My question is, how to I access the default value I set under the publish object?

Thanks in advanced :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

95% of the time, you should never need `getAttribute` when using polymer and published properties. Published properties are accessed as properties on `this`. In the context of your element, `this` is the element. To check against a default value, you could do something like this:

```
(function() {
  var INLINE_DEFAULT = false;

  Polymer('post-card', {
    publish: {
      inline: INLINE_DEFAULT
    },
    ready: function() {
      console.log(this.inline === INLINE_DEFAULT);
    }
  }
}();
```